# Required certificate key usage for signing document

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature, key, self-signed

What's the required key usage/extended key usage for signing documents, eg.PDF, Word, PowerPoint, Excel, etc...

I am going to create a self-signed certificate that is needed to sign those documents. I wonder which key usage is required as there are many types that I can choose.

Note: I just need a self-signed certificate, not from trusted CAs.

Comment: Please be aware that accepted and required values may not only depend on _technical definitions_ of options but also on _profiles_ established by _norms_ and _legal contexts_. Thus, also consider norms and laws applicable in the context of your signatures to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyusage as "digitalSignature" only to create self-signed signing certificate for signing documents.

Additionally, you can add the following:

1. keyUsage

   - nonRepudiation (Good to have, since CA add this in document signing
     certificate)
2. extendedKeyUsage/EnhancedKeyUsage:

   - 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.10.3.12 (Microsoft Document Signing)
   - 1.2.840.113583.1.1.5 (Adobe Authentic Documents Trust)

For more information, you can refer below URL:

https://www.globalsign.com/en/repository/GlobalSign_DocumentSign_for_Adobe_CDS_CPS_v1.3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft proprietary `Document Signing` EKU: https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.10.3.12.html. For key usage you can use `digitalSignature` and optionally `nonRepudiation`.

> Note: I just need a self-signed certificate, not from trusted CAs.

what is the point? The trust to your self-signed certificate must be established on every system where signature will be validated.

Comment: I'll just use a free Let's Encrypt certificate to sign documents as it is trusted and there is a digitalSignature usage there.

Comment: I'm afraid, but Let's Encrypt doesn't offer code/document signing certificates. You can't use these certificates for document signing, you will have to use another (possibly) paid CA service.